# Confusion regarding transfer function and state space conversion in MATLAB

Tags: control, control-system, matlab, state-space

I have values of my state space MATRICES(A,B,C,D). I implemented them in MATLAB.  My code is below, but I got confused when I tried to convert my state space representation to transfer function, especially from converting back again to state space from transfer function as I then get different values in MATRICES. I was expecting the values to be exactly same.

My MATLAB code:

```
clc;clear ;close all
R=100% Defining value of resistance
L=1*10^-6% Inductor
C=1*10^-6% Capacitor
A=[0 -1/L;1/C -1/(R*C)] % Defining matrix A of state space
B=[1/L;0]% Defining matrix B of state space
C=[0 1/R]% Defining matrix C of state space
D=[0]% Defining matrix D of state space
ss(A,B,C,D)% implementing state space 
[num,den]=ss2tf(A,B,C,D)% converting state space to transfer function num & den
tf(num,den)% creating transfer function from num & den
[A1,B1,C1,D1]=tf2ss(num,den)%converting the transfer function to state space
[num1,den1]=ss2tf(A1,B1,C1,D1)% converting new state space matrices to transfer function num1 & den1
tf(num1,den1)%creating transfer function from num1 & den1
[A2,B2,C2,D2]=tf2ss(num1,den1)%converting the transfer function to new  state space matrices A2,B2,C2,D2
```

I was expecting A=A1, B= B1 and C=C1 but none of them is equal. why?

**Update:** I tried to convert my new state space matrices(A1,B1,C1,D1) to transfer function form and I got exactly the original transfer function. What that means is, the transfer function form is not unique (unlike state space.)

When I tried to convert this new transfer function (that was exactly the same as original transfer function,) I got exactly equal matrices. A2=A1,B2=B1 and so on

Why are the state space matrices not the same as the starting/original state space matrices?

Comment: Try these: `p=[4 3 2 1]; r=roots(p); q=poly(r)` and see that `p` is different than `q`. And yet...

Answer (score 3):

For transfer functions, if you restrict it to canonical representation -- i.e., a polynomial in \$s\$ or \$z\$, with the leading coefficient of the denominator polynomial = 1 (i.e., \$D(s) = s^n + a_{n-1}s^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0\$), and no pole-zero cancellations, then the transfer function is unique to the frequency response -- there's a 1:1 correspondence between the set of poles and zeros and the gain on the one hand, and the transfer function on the other.

In state-space representation, there are an *infinite* number of ways to realize a system that has a specific set of poles and zeros, and a given gain.  Moreover, while there are some canonical realizations, there are more than one, and each one is useful in a different circumstance.

So it is *entirely unsurprising* that going from some arbitrary state space description to a transfer function and then to state space again should yield a different representation.  Matlab will always cough up a state space representation that follows its algorithm (whatever it is).  This will probably follow one of the recognized *state space canonical forms* (search on that term).  So unless your starting state-space system happens to follow Matlab's form, then it'll be different after the conversion.

Comment: I have updated my question with more code and more details. I shall be very thankful if you please also try to update your answer according to updated question.

Comment: Please elaborate your lines as i think they are more relevant to my updated question contents  

"Matlab will always cough up a state space representation that follows its algorithm (whatever it is). So unless your starting state-space system happens to follow Matlab's form, then it'll be different after the conversion."

Comment: Search on the term "state space canonical form".  Since there's not a unique transformation from a transfer function to state space, several useful canonical forms have been developed, which allow for easy and obvious algorithms to do the transformation.  In addition to the widely recognized ones, there's nothing keeping a place like the MathWorks from cooking up their own algorithms.